# Interrupt Code Execution

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, components, break

I have the following component based architecture. How can I break out of the Manager's loop which is updating the Components, from within the Update function of a specific Component?

Component

```
class Component
{
    virtual void Update() = 0;
};
```

Manager

```
class Manager
{
    vector<Component*> List;
    void Add(Component* cpnt)
    {
        List.push_back(cpnt);
    }
    void Loop()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            for (auto i = List.begin(); i != List.end(); i++)
                i->Update();
        }
    }
};
```

Example

```
class Example : public Component
{
    void Update()
    {
        // want to break out of mgr's while loop from here
    }
};

int main()
{
    Manager mgr;
    mgr.Add(new Example());
    mrg.Loop();
}
```

(Please note that I ignored accesors in this example for simplicity.)

Comment: +1 for including only the relevant part of the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either throw an exception from `Update` and catch it outside the loop or `break` from the loop depending on the return value of `Update`.

Which one you choose depends on the logic. If breaking out of the loop is a result of a logical error, use an exception.

If it's part of the logic, use a return.

Comment: +1 I wish more people would follow the usage pattern in the last two sentences.

Comment: Thanks, it is part of the logic that the manager ends sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Update` return value, based upon which you may wish not to continue the loop.

You can also use exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Make `Update()` return a code indicating whether to stop or not, and check for that in the `Manager` loop. Or throw an exception, which would be more `C++`-like, and if breaking out is not something that happens too often.

That is, either change `virtual void Update()` into `virtual bool Update()` or similar, with the following `Manager` loop:

```
bool ok = true;
while(ok)
    for (auto i = List.begin(); i != List.end() && ok; i++)
        ok = i->Update();
```

Or make `Update()` throw an exception:

```
void Update()
{
    do stuff;
    if(bad) throw SomeException();
}
```

and wrap the `Manager` loop in a `try`/`catch` clause.

Comment: Could you explain throwing an exception, please?

Comment: If you know nothing about `C++` exceptions, you can read about them [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Comment: Do NOT use exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score -1):

If you can change `Update`, make it return a `bool` telling the manager whether it should break.

```
    while(1)
    {
        for (auto i = List.begin(); i != List.end(); i++)
            if( !i->Update() )
                 goto end_loop;
    }
    end_loop:
```

I've used `goto` to exit the outer loop, you can use a variable to make a double `break` if you're afraid of `goto`.

You can (and should) use `return` instead if there is nothing more to execute in the `Loop`.

Comment: There is much more than executing the loop inside the update functions. Basically all of the component's logic is placed there.

Comment: @sharethis I was talking about `Manager::Loop` after the `while`. If there is some code after the closing bracket of while, you need to break to it. Otherwise you can just `return;`